# What was the manga/doujinshi that "They Were Both Bottoms" originated from?

Tags: meme

A common meme originating from *yuri* is (possible NSFW images in link) ["They Were Both Bottoms"](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/they-were-both-bottoms) which features 2 women in their underwear about to have sex but lamenting at the realization that neither one is willing to take the lead.

On the [Know Your Meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/they-were-both-bottoms) site, it states that the image was originally drawn by Mikawa Miso. However, it doesn't list what the manga/doujinshi was and the link in the citation goes to DynastyScans's 404 page.

So, which of Mikawa Miso's works did the "They Were Both Bottoms" image originate from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It was from [*Neko to Neko no Owaranai Yoru*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/zw2ki2a/neko-to-neko-no-owaranai-yoru)**, which was 1 of 2 works published in 2017.

Conveniently, the sample page from Baka-Updates Manga shows the relevant panel, with its bigger version shown on [the author's tweet](https://twitter.com/mkw_bkn2/status/852540554411778049) (warning: mild NSFW image). The original panel mentioned

> 前略お互いネコでした

with the term "neko" equivalent to the term "uke" / "bottom".

Further reading: [What is the equivalent of "seme" and "uke" in yuri culture?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/28319/2516)